# Emulate waiting on File.Open in C# when file is locked

Tags: c#, file-io, .net-2.0, filestream, ioexception

I have, essentially, the same problem as this poster, but in C#: [Waiting until a file is available for reading with Win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746781/waiting-until-a-file-is-available-for-reading-with-win32)

More information: we have code that calls `File.Open` in one of our projects, that occasionally dies when the file is already opened by another process (**EDIT:** or thread):

```
FileStream stream = File.Open(m_fileName, m_mode, m_access);
/* do stream-type-stuff */
stream.Close();
```

`File.Open` will throw an `IOException` (which is currently quietly swallowed somewhere), whose `HResult` property is `0x80070020` (`ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION`). What I would *like* to do is this:

```
FileStream stream = null;
while (stream == null) {
    try {
        stream = File.Open(m_fileName, m_mode, m_access, FileShare.Read);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        const int ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION = int(0x80070020);
        if (e.HResult != ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION)
            throw;
        else
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
/* do stream-type-stuff */
stream.Close();
```

However, `HResult` is a protected member of `Exception`, and cannot be accessed -- the code does not compile. Is there another way of accessing the `HResult`, or perhaps, another part of .NET I might use to do what I want?

Oh, one final caveat, and it's a doozy: I'm limited to using Visual Studio 2005 and .NET 2.0.

Comment: Note that the `HResult` property is [no longer `protected` as of .NET Framework v4.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.exception.hresult#remarks): "Starting with the .NET Framework 4.5, the HResult property's setter is protected, whereas its getter is public. In previous versions of the .NET Framework, both getter and setter are protected."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can call `Marshal.GetHRForException()` within the `catch` clause to get the error code. No need for reflection:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

if (Marshal.GetHRForException(e) == ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION)
    ....
```

Comment: Is this thread-safe? The code above is running in a thread; many threads will be attempting to call `File.Open` simultaneously.

Comment: I think you meant `System.Runtime.InteropServices`, BTW. :)

Comment: Never mind. MSDN states: "Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of `[Marshal]` are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe."

Comment: Actually, `Marshal.GetExceptionCode()` is wrong, now that I've seen it running. What I actually needed was `Marshal.GetHRForException(e)`. Do you mind updating your answer to accomodate?

Comment: Done! :) Can I get my 5 pts back? ;p

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is using reflection unfortunately. Of course, since you sleep for 1sec between attempts, the performance costs will most likely go unnoticed.