# Ensuring a file is saved to XML before opening it with CHtmlView control

Tags: serialization, mfc, webbrowser-control, tinyxml2

I use this code to **save** the data to XML:

```cpp
bool CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::SaveToXML(CString strFileXML, tinyxml2::XMLDocument& rDocXML)
{
    FILE    *fStream = nullptr;
    CString strError, strErrorCode;
    errno_t eResult;
    bool    bDisplayError = false;
    int     iErrorNo = -1;

    using namespace tinyxml2;

    // Does the file already exist?
    if (PathFileExists(strFileXML))
    {
        // It does, so try to delete it
        if (!::DeleteFile(strFileXML))
        {
            // Unable to delete!
            AfxMessageBox(theApp.GetLastErrorAsString(), MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Now try to create a FILE buffer (allows UNICODE filenames)
    eResult = _tfopen_s(&fStream, strFileXML, _T("w"));
    if (eResult != 0 || fStream == nullptr) // Error
    {
        bDisplayError = true;
        _tcserror_s(strErrorCode.GetBufferSetLength(_MAX_PATH), _MAX_PATH, errno);
        strErrorCode.ReleaseBuffer();
    }
    else // Success
    {
        // Now try to save the XML file
        XMLError eXML = rDocXML.SaveFile(fStream);
        const int fileCloseResult = fclose(fStream);
        if (eXML != XMLError::XML_SUCCESS)
        {
            // Error saving
            bDisplayError = true;
            strErrorCode = rDocXML.ErrorName();
            iErrorNo = rDocXML.GetErrorLineNum();
        }

        if (!bDisplayError)
        {
            if (fileCloseResult != 0)
            {
                // There was a problem closing the stream. We should tell the user
                bDisplayError = true;
                _tcserror_s(strErrorCode.GetBufferSetLength(_MAX_PATH), _MAX_PATH, errno);
                strErrorCode.ReleaseBuffer();
            }
        }
    }

    if (bDisplayError)
    {
        if (iErrorNo == -1)
            iErrorNo = errno;

        strError.Format(IDS_TPL_ERROR_SAVE_XML, strFileXML, strErrorCode, iErrorNo);
        AfxMessageBox(strError, MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The code in itself is fine. Elsewhere in my program I save the file and then go to **display a report**. It uses a XSL transformation with the XML file in a `CHtmlView` browser control:

```cpp
        CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::SaveToXML(strPreviewXML, myDoc);
        if (ePreviewType == PreviewType::Editor)
        {
            if (m_pHtmlPreview != nullptr)
            {
                CString strURL = strPreviewXML;
                if (iBookmarkId != -1)
                    strURL.Format(_T("%s#week%d"), (LPCTSTR)strPreviewXML, iBookmarkId);

                m_pHtmlPreview->Navigate2(strURL, 0, nullptr);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (m_pPrintHtmlPreview != nullptr)
                m_pPrintHtmlPreview->Navigate2(strPreviewXML, 0, nullptr);
        }
    }
```

I am finding that:

- **Sometimes** my preview is **white**, and after a **refresh** it shows.
- At other times if I am working in what I refer to as "weekly mode" and it recreates the XML each week I do get a message about **the file already being in use**. This does **not** always happen.

Is there secure way that we can save to the HDD and then not use the file until it has fully been written to disc?

Comment: How about something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746781/waiting-until-a-file-is-available-for-reading-with-win32)? Loop to wait until the file is available.

Comment: If tinyxml is running on the same thread then file should be available. You can also try `CHtmlView::GetReadyState` to make sure html control does not ignore the navigate request.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I assume `tinyxml2` is running on the same thread. When I do a print preview, I initiate a timer every 250 milliseconds which then calls `GetReadyState`. When the return value is `READYSTATE_COMPLETE` it initiates the preview. But I don't follow this logic when I am just saving the XML file and then updating the view.